# base64 decoding doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display an image from a mysql database in a HTML table with PHP. As I stored the images as BLOBs in the DB, I used the following base64 functions to convert them from binary and display them correctly:

```
$enc=base64_encode($image);
$dec=base64_decode($enc);
echo $dec;
```

I don't know why images continue displaying like this:
[image]

Here is the entire PHP code:

```
<?php
    // Konexio lokala sortu
    $sql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    // Konexioa lokala egiaztatu
    mysql_select_db("quiz") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `Erabiltzaile`";
    $records = mysql_query($sql);
    if (! $records)
    {
         die('Errorea: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_close();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Erabiltzaileak</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Izena</th>
                <th>E-posta</th>
                <th>Pasahitza</th>
                <th>Telefonoa</th>
                <th>Espezialitatea</th>
                <th>Interesak</th>
                <th>Argazkia</th>
            <tr>
        <?php
            while($erabiltzaile=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
                echo "<td>".$erabiltzaile['Izena']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$erabiltzaile['Eposta']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$erabiltzaile['Pasahitza']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$erabiltzaile['Telefonoa']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$erabiltzaile['Espezialitatea']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$erabiltzaile['Interesak']."</td>";
                $image = $erabiltzaile['Argazkia'];
                echo "<td>";
                $enc=base64_encode($image);
                $dec=base64_decode($enc);
                echo $dec;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>

    </table>
</body>
```

It's my first question here, hope the format of the question is good. Sorry about the words in Basque(Argazkia means Picture).

Comment: Store the images in the filesystem.

Comment: The b64 calls are useless. all you're doing is the equivalent of wrapping a box in paper, and then ripping the paper off again. you just end up with the original box. that's **NOT** how you display an image in html.

Comment: If you want to see the image, it needs to be in an `<img>` tag.

Comment: why `$enc=base64_encode($image); $dec=base64_decode($enc);` ? imho it should be just `$dec=base64_decode($image);` but if you just `echo` the image file - what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the base64 code in `data:` URI in an `<img>` tag:

```
$type = getimagesizefromstring($image);
$enc = base64_encode($image);
echo "<td>";
echo "<img src='data:" . $type['mime'] . "';base64," . $enc . "'>";
echo "</td>";
```

`getimagesizefromstring` is available in PHP 5.4+. If you have an older version, you can find a polyfill [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php#113976).

Comment: Thank you Barmar, now the table looks better but images don't display as they should, I get the following: http://i.imgur.com/hzIbkc6.png Would you know why this happens?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that `getimagesize` takes a filename, not the raw image data. I've updated the answer to use `getimagesizefromstring`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work with this:

```
$enc = base64_encode($image);
echo "<td>";
echo '<img src="data:image/;base64,' . $enc . '"/>';
echo "</td>";
```

Without `$type = getimagesize($image);`

Thank you for all the comments and for the answer Barmar! :)